# How to refer to image asset that were imported from a folder import in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, image

I have project structure in Xcode like this:

```
MyProject
  MyProject
    ImportedImages
      Icons
        A.png
    ImagesFolder
      Background
        BG-1280-x-1920.png
```

The folder `ImagesFolder` was imported. Therefore, the file inside such as file `BG-1280-x-1920.png` is also imported. The folder `ImagesFolder` is coloured blue.

Meanwhile, group `ImportedImages` was created. The file image `A.png` was imported manually. The group `ImportedImages` is coloured yellow.

When I tried to run this code:

```
self.backgroundView.image = UIImage(named: "BG-1280-x-1920.png")!
```

It gives me error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.

But if I run this:

```
self.backgroundView.image = UIImage(named: "A.png")!
```

It runs fine. Why? Is there any wrong in my method to access the `BG-1280-x-1920.png` ?

**EDIT:** sorry, I get it now. From this [article](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2012/10/21/xcode-groups-vs-folder-references/), it shows that I need to give full path when accessing files in blue folder, such as:

```
self.backgroundView.image = UIImage(named: "Images/BG/BG-1280-x-1920.png")!
```

Comment: Have you imported whole folder? and is folder is deploying in blue color?

Comment: @Dev_Tandel yes the folder is in blue color. actually, there are many files on that folder, but I just show the one that's relevant.

Comment: @Dev_Tandel sorry, maybe it was misleading: this is the project structure, not the physical folder structure. I've fixed the wording.